# Filter raw string with sheltered simbols, python

Tags: python

Is it any chance to get cities names from the following raw strings without heavy iterations?

```py
'\nSegelbåt \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\
t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tÄlvsborg\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t'

'\nSegelbåt \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t
\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tÄlvsborg\n\t\t\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t', 

'\nButik\nSegelbåt \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tStockholm\n\t\t\t\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t'
```

need to get Älvsborg, Stockholm, etc, that is name of a cities, towns. Names will be different of cource

Function is already heavy with iterations, so that build or add-on functions/methods are preferable.

also it is possible to get them in the following format:

```py
SegelbåtÄlvsborg
ButikSegelbåtStockholm
ButikSegelbåtStockholm
SegelbåtJönköping
SegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
SegelbåtSkaraborg
SegelbåtStockholm
SegelbåtStockholm
SegelbåtHalland
SegelbåtStockholm
ButikSegelbåtHelsingborg
SegelbåtStockholm
ButikSegelbåtKalmar
SegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtÖstergötland
ButikSegelbåt
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
ButikSegelbåtGöteborg
SegelbåtStockholm
ButikSegelbåtHelsingborg
SegelbåtKalmar
SegelbåtGöteborg
```

which doesn't make job easier.

Thank you!

p.s. i can separate letters and sheltered symbols like this in FOR cycle:

```py
letters = ''.join(filter(lambda x: False if x.isspace() else True,
                                     place.get_text()
```

And after that i still need to separate cities names somehow...

Comment: You can just do this, `'input_str.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')` on each strings. Where `input_str` is that string.

Comment: `s.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')` ?

Comment: yes, but when i get something like :ButikSegelbåtHelsingborg where Helsingborg  is a name of the city. then i need somehow separete Helsingborg   from this string which is a cnt find a relaible solution to do

Comment: I specified filter i used to clean \n\t and stuff in the main text above

Comment: Are these 3 different strings ?

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh. Yes, but this is just an example. Actual ammount of the strings is few dozens per request and they are they contain different cities names but general format is like in my example. City name is always in center, surrounded by n/t/

Comment: so you want to keep the space, but remove the `\n` and `\t` ?

Comment: and + i want to separate '\nButik\nSegelbåt  or Segelbåt at the begining of the string, keeping only cities names. I know how to clean n/t's already(example in the main text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `str.split`:

```
In [1]: s = '\nSegelbåt \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tÄlvsborg\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\
  ... t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t'

In [2]: s.split()  # when called with no argument it splits on all whitespace
Out[2]: ['Segelbåt', 'Älvsborg']
```

The city name seems to be the last element:

```
In [3]: s.split()[-1]
Out[3]: 'Älvsborg'
```

It looks like you're parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup. You may find it easier to select the proper elements directly instead of parsing what `.get_text()` produces.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I managed to separate it myself just using my filter from the main text + slice [15:] to remove first possible text and keep only city name , but your solution is better for sure. If you are interested in what i am doing - i parsing this page https://www.blocket.se/hela_sverige?q=Smaragd&cg=1060&w=3&st=s&ps=&pe=&c=1062&ca=11&is=1&l=0&md=li  to get adresses of the boats. If you check element that is in charge for adress you can see the problem why am i doing what i doing.

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich: You can access the city with `.contents`: for example, `[h.contents[-1].strip() for h in soup.select('article[id^="item_"] header[itemprop]')]`

Comment: i did it like following: places = bsObj.find_all("header", {"itemprop": "itemOffered"}); letters = place.get_text().split()[-1]; here we go